# Getting a subset of items: Is it better to user PagerDefault and limit, or get'em'all and array_splice?

Tags: 7, database

I want to pull some number of nodes out of the database for rendering and display.  There are several ways to do this, two of which would be:

1. do a `db_select(...)->extend('PagerDefault');` and add a `->limit()`
   clause to specify the number of items to be returned.
2. do the `db_select()` without the `PagerDefault`, and use
   `array_slice` to get the desired number of items.

Any advice on the relative advantages of these, especially from a performance perspective?  I've done a few informal tests that suggest about a 100% penalty for using `PagerDefault`, but I wouldn't want to claim these are definitive.  Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`range()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3Arange/7) instead:

```
db_select(...)->range(0, 10);
```

Comment: Aha -- another nook/cranny I didn't know about.  Thanks!